# Sign .key with OpenSSL in Python

Tags: python, openssl

I have the following key, test.key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Which I need to sign using OpenSSL with SHA256 and convert it in base64.

The data used to sign the key is the following string: `testdata` which is stored in the file `data.txt`

On a shell prompt, my reference commands are the following ones:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign test.key -out signed data.txt
openssl base64 -in signed -out signed_b64
```

Which produces:

```
wrYUICAPdaOyeMKd/4+5bYEsfYQD12iO1EwGzCn4K7+M0BMU4jb6Bzbuv6VKGGU0
1ax9o/oyrn5RwXUwPMLGKf8uBZORK4gPxM7yRxX74GHgigzSN6Cj+S3/8QrQsXw0
RvYuqm1Az/7CSppe6sSxaVWSh+mwa9VfRZRtQg9pQTBfOuv7TeDvTv9+CTLTaJvZ
jINylZbUHJNcRScqNeQC55Ys5VeD1Ub+fzu0Kxt9pBkC9tOQ2x7rc11bsvU02S3J
D695A570OQgG5ou3fvkibZx7CXgwpyAhACeCMQE8JrJfwyWLE1SziafBWhBvKZK2
hczVlKlOQzpOpCGy5JiVYQ==
```

Now I would like to reproduce the same in Python, I'm using this code:

```
from OpenSSL.crypto import load_certificate, load_privatekey, sign, FILETYPE_PEM
import base64

key_file_string = open('test.key', "rb").read()
pkey = load_privatekey(FILETYPE_PEM, key_file_string)
data = 'testdata'
signed = sign(pkey, data, 'sha256')
signed_base64 = base64.b64encode(signed)
```

Which produces a different result:

```
mpVCNEp/Oqb4DYOmWsT/z7VswOjl5WbB8h9XX1PwM9IEwGR+B420sUBYGzuQGz/p6jMsq4x0hx8Yn/lm1f0KyeqA4FNqvpYD75+SES0sK5rWZOdhvfxdGYU8xeWnOaCHfQvTj9Lh/4DOIZWWF94uXNWT7FSNDvRKGgqbLy2NPRe2li2UgRYRDRReifJlsqfBKVZ0iHbomwZ7plaihZa5GCnDx2wnpgr5QAlI131TpjpX1IgRDvWORY6zbziKUzT+qCsQhlF9ii7L7W31VKy+AUO97oKyqHVyfdCqwiXipOMm/++zgoEdCtu6ZPs4qTyeM/eEnwCjdJY9foTj8gD6bA==
```

What am I getting wrong?